# Get value from JSON API request and display it as text in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, request

I feel like this is a really simple question but I can't find the help I need, so I'm turning to you.

If you go to this request URL: https://public.ecologi.com/users/lightlysalted/impact
, you will see a very basic JSON response with two keys and their respective values:

```
{"trees":383,"carbonOffset":12.52}
```

I would like to put the trees number in one paragraph and the carbon offset in another paragraph on a HTML page, like the below:

```
<p class="trees">383</p>
<p class="carbonoffset">12.52</p>
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to fetch the result. You can use the native [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for that.

Then when the json data is received you need to find your html elements, here we loop on the keys and then query the element whose class matches the received json key with `document.getElementsByClassName(key)`. Once we found the element we input the corresponding value with `elem[0].textContent = json[key]`.

```
fetch("https://public.ecologi.com/users/lightlysalted/impact")
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((json) => {
  Object.keys(json).forEach((key) => {
    const elem = document.getElementsByClassName(key);
    elem[0].textContent = json[key];
  });
})
```

fiddle: https://jsbin.com/tetuyemoqo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

html doesn't support anything like this out of the box. You'll need to:

1. fetch the data from the API
2. parse the data
3. update the html

In general I recommend a framework like vuejs to do this, but you can also do it with javascript and editing the `innerHtml` of the `p` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the response body into a JSON Object using `var json = JSON.parse(response.body)`. After that you can access the attributes of the JSON using `json.trees` and `json.carbonOffset` respectively.
You'll then manipulate the content of the HTML useing `document.querySelector('.trees').innerHTML(json.trees)` and `document.querySelector('.carbonoffset').innerHTML(json.carbonOffset)`.